# Gurobi can't add constraints

Tags: java, linear-programming, gurobi

I'm writing a program in Java to solve a MIP problem with Gurobi. This problem requires a lot of constraints and variables but the first ones cannot be added to my model. Deeper in the problem, when I try to add a constraint the model show it(read through debugging),but `row_no` is equal to -1.
First things first:

- Create multi-dimensional matrix of variables:

  ```
      GRBVar[][] x = new GRBVar[iMax][jMax];
      for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
              x[i][j] = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.SEMIINT, "xi" + i + "j" + j);
          }
      }
  ```
- Add Constraints (looks like Xij < 10):

  ```
      for (int i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {

              GRBLinExpr lhs = new GRBLinExpr();
              GRBLinExpr rhs = new GRBLinExpr();

              lhs.addTerm(1.0, x[i][j]]);
              rhs.addConstant(10);

              model.addConstr(lhs, GRB.LESS_EQUAL, rhs, "Vi" + i + "j" + j);
          }
      }
  ```
- Debug project: there are `iMax * jMax` columns, `iMax * jMax` variables, `iMax * jMax` contraints (with `row_no` = -1) and 0 rows.

Any idea?

### EDIT

I'm not certain about the use of `row_no`, but I suppose that Gurobi (**from an abstract point of view)** organizes data into a pseudo-matrix where variables are stored as columns and constraints as rows. 
Why I say that? Because every times that I add a variable the counter of the columns grow by 1 and its `col_no` are associated to a particular column, instead when I add a constraint the counter of the rows doesn't change.

[image: Gurobi model debug]

Columns: http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/java_grbmodel_getcol.html
Rows:http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.0/refman/java_grbmodel_getrow.html

### EDIT 2

I don't have any problems with columns, rows or anything else, but when I try to solve the relaxed model, Gurobi shows this output:

```
Optimize a model with 0 rows, 1475400 columns and 0 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range    [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Objective range [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Bounds range    [1e+00, 1e+03]
  RHS range       [0e+00, 0e+00]
Presolve removed 0 rows and 1475400 columns
Presolve time: 0.36s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed
Iteration    Objective       Primal Inf.    Dual Inf.      Time
       0    0.0000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00      1s

Solved in 0 iterations and 0.72 seconds
Optimal objective  0.000000000e+00
```

The solution is feasible, but can't show any useful information. I tought the I should update the model only after adding variables, not constraints. Additionaly, I read from Gurobi Documentation that if the model needs to be update its throws an Exception (not my case):

> "The most common symptom of a missing update is a NOT_IN_MODEL
>   exception, which indicates that the object you are trying to reference
>   isn't in the model yet"

### EDIT 3

I've followed your suggest of update the model (after adding constraints) and everythings works correctly. I supposed that it wasn't mandatory but, in contrast of the documentation (and the code examples), it is.

Comment: I do not completely understand: When you solve the model, are the constraints really violated? Or what is exactly the effect of row_no=-1?

Comment: And what is the practical effect? Does Gurobi solve your model correctly or not?

Comment: PS: Maybe a model.update() is required to see all effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that your model shows strange behaviour because all your variables have 0.0 as coefficient in the objective function. Furthermore, setting all variables to zero is a feasible solution.

While I cannot explain the internal mechanism of Gurobi for setting rows to zero, it certainly gives the correct answer for this (strange kind of) model.